# Rigging: yaw + pitch problem

Tags: rigging, bones, drivers

I have a problem rigging a model I did.

I want to rig the base of the cannon so that it is divided into two pieces. I want the top part to be able to yaw and pitch, and the bottom one to not yaw, but still be able to pitch correctly (second picture).

[image: rigged model]

[image: model base showing desired rotation]

Here is the original post: http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?383916-Help-rigging-a-sci-fi-cannon

and here is the blend file:
[image: Dowload the blend from BSE]

Comment: The problem is 1 bone cannot operate 2 separate parts. You need 2 bones, first for rotation left/right and second parented to first for tilting back/forth.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean for the bottom element to yaw (turn left and right) but not to pitch (forward and back). Either way, you can lock any bone to the desired rotation by clicking on the appropriate padlock icon next to the x/y/z rotational axes for the bone at the top of the Properties panel.